# How to iterate a inner Hashmap in drools

Tags: hashmap, drools

I have a use case where i need to use a hashmap inside another hashmap like `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>` . Now I want to iterate the inner map based on the key of the outer Map using Drools . How can i achieve this in drools .

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "inner hash map" - there are as many inner hash maps as there are entries in the "outer" hash map. If you want to loop over all entries in all the contained hash maps, you'll have to write a nested loop. If you need to iterate over all entries of a single inner hash map based on a key for the outer map, then you retrieve the value, which is a map, and iterater over its entries.

If you need to do this in a rule's consequence, you use the same statements as in Java.

Otherwise, it's an issue where the map is and why you need to iterate, so no code can be gjven.